# Hibernate search get a row by a field value

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I'm new to hibernate and Spring.

I have Student class that have:

```
studentId;  
firstName;  
lastName;   
yearLevel;
getters/setters
...etc
```

I want to search a student by its firstName or lastName.
So I tried this method in StudentDaoImpl.java:

```
@Override
public Student getStudentByLastName(String lastName) {
    return (Student)session.getIdentifier(lastName);
}
```

And it does not work the only one that works is searching by studentId:

```
public Student getStudentByLastName(int studentId) {

    return (Student)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Student.class,studentId);
}
```

Is there a way to get the Student object by searching a field value like lastName or firstName ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuld use camelCase in naming variables (firstName instead of firstname etc.).
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname

> Bean naming conventions
>
> The convention is to use the standard Java convention for instance
>   field names when naming beans. That is, bean names start with a
>   lowercase letter, and are camel-cased from then on. Examples of such
>   names would be (without quotes) 'accountManager', 'accountService',
>   'userDao', 'loginController', and so forth.
>
> Naming beans consistently makes your configuration easier to read and
>   understand, and if you are using Spring AOP it helps a lot when
>   applying advice to a set of beans related by name.